# Browsing speed on Wubi (Ubuntu 10.10) slow compared to that on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu

I have installed Wubi (Ubuntu 10.10) recently. It takes more time to boot than Windows. But my main concern is that **my browsing speed is much slower compared to that on Windows 7**. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

This can't be (totally) resolved. Wubi means you run Linux on "NTFS", it's just not for desktop use. Wubi is there for people who want to try Linux/Ubuntu.

The browsing speed I guess will be the cache. [Here](http://lifehacker.com/#!5687850/speed-up-firefox-by-moving-your-cache-to-ram-no-ram-disk-required) is an article how to speed up this. It'll use more memory, but it'll render faster.

However.. and I'm really honest here, on Windows pages get rendered much faster *FOR ME* (notice the FOR ME part!). I have tried many distributions and still using Linux on some of my PCs but no. You could say its all about the openGL and stuff which will come with Firefox 4 ..but no. It's always been snappier.

Also, we talk about your browser render here. What about your network driver? That's the other suspect. Video driver? What VGA you've got?

Comment: This is my network driver info 
Description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
.Here's the VGA:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)